# Prevent webpack/Laravel mix from transforming promises/async to _asyncToGenerator functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webpack, es6-promise, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel-mix/webpack to generate my JS code, but it generates _asyncToGenerator, although my system/browsers support async functions out of the box.
What do I do to prevent the codding from being converted to a (very clumsy) function called _asyncToGenerator instead of just keep it as it is - a simple async function?

I've tried putting "target: es2017'" in webpack.mix.js file, but it throws an erro that "configuration object that does not match the API schema".

I've searched a lot through the Internet and no success so far...

I'm using:

- laravel-mix@5.0.9
- webpack@4.46.0
- vue@2.6.8

For example, this clear and fine code:

```
async saveFileToDisk(blob, fileName) {
      try {
        const fileHandle = await self.showSaveFilePicker({
          suggestedName: fileName,
          types: [
            {
              description: "File",
              // ...
            },
          ],
        });

        const writeFile = async (fileHandle, contents) => {
          // Create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to.
          const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
          // Write the contents of the file to the stream.
          await writable.write(contents);
          // Close the file and write the contents to disk.
          await writable.close();
        };
        // write file
        writeFile(fileHandle, blob).then(() => console.log("FILE DOWNLOADED!!!"));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

is being converted into this:

```
saveFileToDisk: function saveFileToDisk(blob, fileName) {
      return _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/_babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.mark(function _callee2() {
        var fileHandle, writeFile;
        return _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.wrap(function _callee2$(_context2) {
          while (1) {
            switch (_context2.prev = _context2.next) {
              case 0:
                _context2.prev = 0;
                _context2.next = 3;
                return self.showSaveFilePicker({
                  suggestedName: fileName,
                  types: [{
                    description: "File" // ...

                  }]
                });

              case 3:
                fileHandle = _context2.sent;

                writeFile = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
                  var _ref3 = _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/_babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.mark(function _callee(fileHandle, contents) {
                    var writable;
                    return _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
                      while (1) {
                        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
                          case 0:
                            _context.next = 2;
                            return fileHandle.createWritable();

                          case 2:
                            writable = _context.sent;
                            _context.next = 5;
                            return writable.write(contents);

                          case 5:
                            _context.next = 7;
                            return writable.close();

                          case 7:
                          case "end":
                            return _context.stop();
                        }
                      }
                    }, _callee);
                  }));

                  return function writeFile(_x, _x2) {
                    return _ref3.apply(this, arguments);
                  };
                }(); // write file


                writeFile(fileHandle, blob).then(function () {
                  return console.log("FILE DOWNLOADED!!!");
                });
                _context2.next = 11;
                break;

              case 8:
                _context2.prev = 8;
                _context2.t0 = _context2["catch"](0);
                console.log(_context2.t0);

              case 11:
              case "end":
                return _context2.stop();
            }
          }
        }, _callee2, null, [[0, 8]]);
      }))();
    },
```

I just want it to keep the original code. No transformations!